# React: cannot read property of undefined when passing in my onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure why I am getting `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClickSimilar'` `of undefined"` error when trying to use my function when mapping the array.

```
     handleClickSimilar = (d) => {
        console.log("testing click") 
    }


 render() {
      (...rest of my component)  
      <div className="bottom-content-right">
        <h3>Participating countries:</h3>
        {otherCountries && otherCountries.map(function(d, idx){
          return (<div onClick={() => this.handleClickSimilar(d)} key={idx}>{d}</div>)
        })}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `otherCountries.map` function an arrow function (i.e **(d, idx) =>** ).

Replace `otherCountries.map(function(d, idx){` with `otherCountries.map((d, idx) =>{`

So it will be like

```
{otherCountries && otherCountries.map((d, idx) => {
  return (<div onClick={() => this.handleClickSimilar(d)} key={idx}>{d}</div>)
})}
```

Comment: ah I'm not passing the context down, huh?  Just for my own knowledge, if I didn't want to use the fat arrow , how could i bind the context? Thanks!!

Comment: There are multiple options for doing that, 
See `6. Method Specific` here for your usecase https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/